# Change SciTE background colour when Find highlights the word I'm looking for?

Tags: editor, text

I'm using SciTE. I'd like to change the background colour to something very bright that's easy to spot. Any ideas/suggestions? Thanks so much.

[image: find highlight]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That property can be changed by editing `/usr/share/scite/SciTEGlobal.properties` and then changing this lines:

```
selection.fore
selection.back
selection.alpha
```

which are BTW used for setting the colors for displaying selected text.

For example, for yellow background and red text, without translucency, it would look like:

```
selection.fore=#FF0000
selection.back=#FFFF00
# selection.alpha
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also edit the properties for a single user by editing/adding to the user's SCITE properties `/home/user/.SciTEUser.properties`. This file is accessible directly from inside SciTE via the menu `Options -> Open User Options`. I find that an easy way of doing this is to open both the global properties and the user properties side by side and copying from the global file the properties that I want to change for my user.

The advantages of using the user properties file are threefold:

1. If you ever migrate your user to a different machine by simply copying `/home/user` your changes will be preserved (the new machine will most likely have a fresh install of SciTE with an unmodified global properties file).
2. Changes to the global properties file will affect all users on the system, not just your user.
3. Future updates to SciTE could potentially overwrite your changes to the global properties file.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
caret.line.back=#FFFFFF
caret.line.back.alpha=0
```

in User Options File or else.

Comment: Please add some more information to your answer. As it stands,  it's too short to make for a good answer.